# Awk: add modified column to file and keep original one

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with two columns:

```
path/path/target1.target2 column2
```

Using awk I want to print:

```
column1 column2 target1 target2
```

I tried the following to do the modifications but then I lose the original columns.

```
$ awk '{gsub("\\..*","", $(gsub(".*/","", $1))); gsub(".*_","", $1); print $0}'
target1 column2
```

How can I do this? Can you explain the behaviour?

Comment: In your example output is `column1` actually meant to be `path/path/target1.target2`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain the algorithm in words. For example: can we assume you will _always_ have _just one_ `.` after the last `/`? Can you also have lines like `path.path/path/target1.target2`? How about `path/path/nottarget.target1.target2.nottarget`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an `awk` way:

```
$ awk '{ 
         split($1,parts,"."); 
         sub(".*/","",parts[1]); 
         print $1, $2, parts[1], parts[2]
       }' file
path/path/target1.target2 column2 target1 target2
```

As for why yours didn't work, as [Roaima explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745728/22222), it's because you were changing the value of `$1` so could no longer print it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `sed` rather than `awk`:

```
sed -E 's!([^/]*)\.([^ ]*) (.*)!& \1 \2!'
```

Output from your single line example:

```
path/path/target1.target2 column2 target1 target2
```

As for the reason your own `awk` command replaces the fields, the documentation for `gsub` (see `man awk`) writes,

> **`gsub(r,s,t)`  `gsub(r,s)`** Global substitution, every match of regular expression `r` in variable `t` is replaced by string `s` […]

In other words, where you have provided a value for `t`, such as the `$1` in `gsub(".*/","", $1)` it is *replaced* with the substitution. You need to copy `$1` to a separate variable before applying `gsub`, or else use the non-standard `gensub` to return the modified string.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{n=split($1,a,"[/.]"); print $0, a[n-1], a[n]}' file
path/path/target1.target2 column2 target1 target2
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{x=$1; gsub(/.*\/|\./,OFS,x); print $0 x}' file
path/path/target1.target2 column2 target1 target2
```

There's some fundamental things wrong with your original script that rather than trying to explain here you should just get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and read about `gsub()` and what `$` means.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*...since there's a `sed` answer, why not Perl and/or Raku?*

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split(:skip-empty, /  \.  |  ^ .* <[/]> /)>>.words.flat; say @a.raku;'  file

#OR (more simply)

~$ -ne 'my @a = .split(:skip-empty, /  \.  |  ^ .* <[/]> /).words; say @a.raku;'   file
```

Sample Input:

```
path/path/target1.target2 column2
```

Sample Output:

```
path/path/target1.target2 column2 target1 target2
```

Briefly, input is read linewise with the `-ne` non-autoprinting command line flags, `split` on *either* a `.` dot *or* the path text starting from the beginning of the line to the last `/`, then broken into whitespace-separated `words` (i.e. columns). This is stored into the `@a` array. For output, the initial line `$_` is printed unchanged, followed by the first two elements of the `@a` array.

https://raku.org